# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with a regex in java.

When I try to use this regex:

```
 ^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

I get the following error

```
"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )"
```

I don't know how to handle that error.
I already tried to double the backslashes, but it didn't work. 
I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Java error or a Regex error?

Comment: well you have a \d and it is not in the valid ones

Comment: doubling the backslashes should work. Are you sure you didn't miss one?

Comment: Try escaping your regex: as '\\d'.

Comment: Note that you have three instances of `\d` in your code. You need to escape them all.

Comment: Since Java looks for special escape sequences in Strings (the ones it happily provided to you as the error) you have to escape the backslash in order to use it as a plain backslash '\\' in the regex string.

Comment: Java doesn't have any python-like `r"raw\strings"` nor perl-like `'single\quotes'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work `^(?:(?:([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\\d):)?([0-5]?\\d)$`

The reason is that the listed symbols in the error message have special meaning, but `\d` is not one of those defined special symbols for using `\`, this means you have to escape it (by adding an extra `\` in front of the symbol).

Comment: Help  me to fix this in java "/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/"

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you're writing regular expressions in Java, remember to escape the `\` characters used in the string that defines the regular expression. In other words, if your regular expression contains one `\`, then you HAVE to write two `\\`. For example, your code should look like this:

```
^(?:(?:([01]?\\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\\d):)?([0-5]?\\d)$
```

Why, you ask? because in Java's strings, `\` is the escape character used to denote special characters (example: tabs, new lines, etc.) and if a string contains a `\` then it must itself be escaped, by prepending another `\` in front of it. Hence, `\\`.

For the record, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) is the Java language specification page listing the valid escape characters and their meanings, notice the last one:

```
\b  backspace
\t  horizontal tab
\n  linefeed
\f  form feed
\r  carriage return
\"  double quote
\'  single quote
\\  backslash
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use notepad++ with find / and replace with //

Comment: What is the point of replacing `/` with `//`? It is ``\`` which is special in regex or string literal so it needs escaping.