# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) with defined set of String

Tags: android, string, invalid-characters

I am trying to hard-code String but it gives me this error
    "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )"
Here is the String

```
value is [{"timeStamp":"11\/05\/2014 11:11:28","
```

how to hardcode this string? I tried but got mentioned issue.

I tried this URL [invalid escape seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178955/invalid-escape-sequence-valid-ones-are-b-t-n-f-r)
 but not got any clue where is the issue!
How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

> String value = "[{\"timeStamp\":\"11/05/2014 11:11:28\",";

There's no reason to escape `/` so instead of `\/` you should just have `/`:

```
String value = "[{\"timeStamp\":\"11/05/2014 11:11:28\",";
```

**EDIT**

> I know there is no reason but this is a fixed string and I need to do this.

If you need to preserve `\/` then you do this wrong. This is correct escaping:

```
String value = "[{\"timeStamp\":\"11\\/05\\/2014 11:11:28\",";
```

Comment: I know there is no reason but this is a fixed string and I need to do this.

Comment: Then you do this wrong, see edited answer